# Repair corrupted flash drive

Tags: usb-drive

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
My flash drive was corrupted (doesn't clear the bin) probably, due to removal without unmounting.
I tired "fsck" and got:

sudo fsck /dev/sdb1
[sudo] password for igor:

fsck from util-linux 2.34

fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)

0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.

1. Remove dirty bit
2. No action

?

What should be done next? Thank you.

Comment: open Disks, select your USB Device and at the top you have 3 dots.. Click there and then Format Disk..

Comment: Thank you. I tried left button, right button, double-click, but didn't see any dots or option "format." Any way around?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the answer is found on

https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-format-usb-drive-in-the-terminal/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fat fsck is notorious for requiring heavy manual intervention. I recommend keeping the dirty bit as is (option 2), as it is the least important of every problem, and there are more manual actions to be done. Only after fully fixing the rest should the dirty bit be cleaned.